# Discord bot sending random messages

Tags: python, discord

I would like to make a discord bot that sends a random message, out of a list of messages, into a specified channel every 24h. How would I do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aiocron](https://github.com/gawel/aiocron/) for the discord bot to schedule the message to a specific channel.

I have done something similair and here is the code I have used to randomly message a channel.

You will need a token.txt file with your discord token and a channel.txt with the channel ID.

```
import discord
import aiocron
import random

TOKEN = open("token.txt","r").readline()

random_messages = ['list', 'of', 'random', 'messages', 'foo', 'bar']

# this will run at 4:00 AM of the server time every day
# follows the logic of normal cron

@aiocron.crontab('00 4 * * *')
async def cronjob():
    # reads the channel ID from a channel.txt file
    CHANNEL_ID = open("channel.txt","r").readline()
    # sets the channel info
    channel = client.get_channel(int(CHANNEL_ID))
    # uses the random library to select a message from the list
    message = random_messages[random.randrange(0, len(random_messages))]
    # sends the random message
    await channel.send(message)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score -1):

The first thing i would do is look at the [discord api quickstart](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) to learn how to get started with a bot. Then for the 24 hour part it gets a little hard. For example, if you wanted to print “hello world” every 24 hours you would use this code.

```py
import time 
while True:
   time.sleep(86400)
   print(“hello world”)
```

Importing the time module, repeating forever, waiting 1 day in seconds, printing hello world. The one problem with this is that the computer is on 24/7. I cant really think of a fix for this, but if you want simple, you can do it this way.

For the discord code use the example quickstart. To start go [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discord.html) to make an application. Use the discord api reference to figure everything else out. Make sure to look up anything you are confused on.